# Connection pooling for RABBITMQ in PHP

Tags: php, rabbitmq, connection-pooling, pecl

I want to use RabbitMQ in my project.It's mainly written in PHP hosted by Apache2 server.To deal with RabbitMQ,I choose PECL extension.And I've read in somewhere something like:
"*the connection is expensive so we use channel.You can have many channels per one connection*"

The Problem is I can't figure out -in such environment- how to reuse connection and make something like pooling.
So any help??

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can pool connections but you can create one and it can have as many channels you want.

The connection is a long lived tcp connection so how can you pool these to reuse.

You can use phpamqp_lib from videla, its simple to use.